# ARIMA Modelling in Python

Tags: python, sas, statsmodels

I am trying o transform a SAS Based ARIMA MOdel into a Python based arima model

The code on SAS looks like :

```
proc arima data=temp;
identify var=c3 nlag=12;run;
identify var=c3(1);run;
estimate p=1 q=1/*noint*/ method=ml;run;
estimate p=2 q=0 /*noint*/ method=ml;run;
outlier;run;
forecast lead=&lead id=tc_date interval=week printall out=forecast_ARIMA;
run;
```

quit;

The data temp contains 2 columns : Date and c3 ratings(which I need to predict though ARIMA)

and the python code I created for the following code is :

from statsmodels import tsa as tsa

```
p1 = 2
d1 = 0
q1 = 0
temp = tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(temp.c3.values, [p1, d1, q1])
model1 = temp.fit(trend='nc' , disp = False) 
pred1 = model1.predict(start=0, end=len(ts_data)-1)
```

But the predicted values that I get from SAs and python processes are quite different, 
Is my process correct ? If yes why are the values computed different, and If no , what should be the python process?

Thank you

Comment: ** pred1 = model1.predict(start=0, end=len(temp-1)

Comment: Did you compare the estimated coefficients? There is too little information to guess what is going on. I'm not familiar with the SAS procedure, but I would check whether unspecified default options are different.